# How would you characterize the term "this" in java?

Tags: java, variables, this, instance

Simple question, I know what `this` does in Java but is `this` considered an instance variable belonging to the class?

Comment: Alright thank you for showing me the existing question. I apologize for not noticing it earlier before posting this question. You may close this question. @Jigar Joshi

Comment: You may be able to delete it if you wish. It is already closed.

Comment: It is a duplicate question, but not a dumb one. In Scala, they're still evolving what "this" can do. (e.g. pattern matching)

Comment: The way I would define `this` is that it's an immutable reference value (as opposed to a mutable reference variable) which refers to the current object instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is not an **instance variable** belonging to the class. `this` is a reference to an **instance** of the current class.

Comment: `this` is a reference, and a reference is not an instance.

Comment: Actually, the JLS says this: *"When used as a primary expression, the keyword this denotes a value that is a reference to the object ..."*.  Hence `this` is an expression, whose value is a reference.

Comment: @StephenC *Non sequitur.* A literal can also be used as a primary expression: that doesn't mean it *is* an expression.

Comment: @EJP - OK, "hence" is too strong.  But in the real point is that `this` is an expression that evaluates to a reference.  It is not a reference.  (Just like a variable name is a primary that evaluates to a value ... not the value itself.)